# Is it a good idea to backup/restore Neo4j databases with Kubernetes VolumeSnapshot?

Tags: kubernetes, neo4j, backup, database-backups

I have a Neo4j database running on Kubernetes. I want to make scheduled backups for the database. I know that Neo4j provides [a set of tools for backup and restore](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/). However, Kubernetes [`VolumeSnapshot`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/) also looks viable for backup and restore.

I wonder if it's a good idea to use Kubernetes `VolumeSnapshot` to backup/restore Neo4j databases? Will it cause errors like inconsistency database status or faulty disk problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if it is not supported by the database, then it is a bad idea.

Think of your database as being stored across:

1. Database files on disk
2. Page cache (in volatile memory)
3. Write ahead transaction logs on disk

A volume snapshot would not save enough information to get a consistent state of your database (unless the database is gracefully shut down).

Use the set of tools provided for backup/restore